# Flutter Web Problem: Uploading on Firebase Storage

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, file-upload, flutter-web

I'm trying to upload pictures with my Flutter Web App but what I get is the Following error:

```
TypeError: dart.global.firebase.storage is not a function
    at Object.storage$ [as storage] (http://localhost:64863/packages/firebase/src/top_level.dart.lib.js:90:100)
    at product_card._ProductCardState.new._newProduct (http://localhost:64863/packages/delivery/admin_pages/product_card.dart.lib.js:2576:38)
    at _newProduct.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:37956:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:37810:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:32771:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:33319:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:33357:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:33199:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:33222:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:38071:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:38077:13)
    at http://localhost:64863/dart_sdk.js:33574:9
```

In the index.html I have the following lines in the body:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

I already tried other versions of the gstatic.com/firebasejs but nothing seems to work.

**Flutter doctor:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.24.0-10.2.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73 darwin-x64, locale it-IT)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

**Flutter upgrade:**

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel beta
Flutter 1.24.0-10.2.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 022b333a08 (4 weeks ago) • 2020-11-18 11:35:09 -0800
Engine • revision 07c1eed46b
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-29.10.beta)
```

**Storage rules:**

```
rules_version = ‘2’; 
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have no problem in using Cloud Firestore functionalities, but when I try tu use:

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
...
fb.storage()...
```

I get the error I wrote above.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: try to add the firebase storage script ```<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>```